# How do I disable the "Show cursor when ctrl is pressed" option in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, cursor, locate

I can't find it anywhere, and it's interfering with my work. I tried it just for fun, but now I can't figure out how I turned it on! Please help. Tweaks, code, or whatever. I need it disabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The option to turn it off should be in the Mouse tab of the Mouse and Touchpad options which is in the settings menu.